# clearinterval is not working for the following code

Tags: jquery

What's wrong with the code, I am unable to stop setInterval.

> Error: changedHandler_BB is undefined.

...

```
var changedHandler_BB = setInterval(function() {

    $("#wc_room_container_BB").addClass('active_chat_block_blink_effect');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#wc_room_container_BB").removeClass('active_chat_block_blink_effect');
    }, 500);

}, 1000);
```

...

```
$("#wc_block_BB").click(function(){

    var newID = $("#LatestLastID_BB").val();

    $("#worldchat_last_id_BB").val(newID);

    clearInterval(changedHandler_BB);
});
```

Comment: Possibly because `changedHandler_BB` is not a global variable and has no meaning in the scope were `clearInterval` is being called.

Comment: Is this `var changedHandler_BB = setInterval(function()` inside another function ?

Comment: thanks for reply, I just copy this code from other website, can you pls help me, how to do fix it.

Comment: You are not showing your full code...

Comment: yes, that's in other funtion.

Comment: I am new to this community...I was trying to post full code, but edition of this site is not acceptiong

Comment: If you remove `var` from `changedHandler_BB` the variable will be global and you can access it from everyware. `var changedHandler_BB =` -> `changedHandler_BB =`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment's above - you defined `changedHandler_BB` inside a function. You need to define that in outer scope so that it become accessible in another functions

try this -

```
var changedHandler_BB;

function someFunction() {
    changedHandler_BB = setInterval(function () {
        $("#wc_room_container_BB").addClass('active_chat_block_blink_effect');
        setTimeout(function () {
           $("#wc_room_container_BB").removeClass('active_chat_block_blink_effect');
        }, 500);
    }, 1000);
}
$("#wc_block_BB").click(function () {
    var newID = $("#LatestLastID_BB").val();
    $("#worldchat_last_id_BB").val(newID);
    clearInterval(changedHandler_BB);
});
```

Comment: oh Thanks alot, its working perfect now! thanks alot one more time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove 'var':

```
changedHandler_BB = setInterval(function() {...}); //setting variable on global scope {window.changedHandler_BB }
```

Comment: thanks for reply, Now error has removed now but still clearInterval is not working

Comment: Yes, downvoting because that is dangerous advice.  There are plenty of ways to create the variable in the correct scope without carelessly tossing it into the global scope. If nothing else, assign it directly to the `window` object, but don't just drop the `var` declaration.

Comment: I'm not the down-voter but remember, [Global variables are evil](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination/).

Comment: @Derek Henderson Judging by customized name of variable, i don't think it could be a problem here, anyway, you are correct, better is to use closure.

Answer (score 0):

`changedHandler_BB` is in another function.  Thus, it is in that function's scope and not in scope accessible by `clearInterval` inside your click event handler.  This is why it is undefined when you attempt to access it.

You need to make sure that either `changedHandler_BB` is in the same scope as your click event listener or can be otherwise accessed by it.